# Why is this site mostly legal advise rather than literature discussion?

Tags: discussion

Why is this site mostly legal advise rather than literature discussion?

I wanted to discuss some poetry I am trying to write but I did not find any similar questions. Instead there are questions about copyright, publishers and so on.

Is it designed to be so?

Comment: I came here expecting a totally different community and I was disappointed. Turned out this Writers Q&A doesn't allow literature/poetry which is OT.
I've put up a quick and dirty proposal on Area51: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/22524/poetry-literature-vs-writers

Maybe you can give feedback there, and maybe help with the creation of another Stackexchange site about those topics

Answer (score 7):

1) There happen to be several questions about copyright and publishers which were all asked at once recently (quite a few by the same person, I might add). If you scroll backwards, you'll see questions on a variety of topics. So no, Writers SE is not designed to be a site solely giving legal advice.

2) This is not a "discussion" site in any case. If you have a question about an aspect of your poetry you need help with, by all means ask, but the question needs to be concrete, answerable, and with the potential for others to find it useful. You can find other questions people have asked about poetry under the poetry tag.

https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry

Comment: "This is not a "discussion" site in any case." I can't possibly upvote this enough times. To add to this, please note that this isn't a literature site by any means, it's a site for writers, editors, publishers, and so on.